# Dismissing modal in iOS 7 Storyboard results in warning

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, modalviewcontroller

I am using a storyboard in my design for iOS 7 and I am getting the following warning when I dismiss a modal:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UITabBarController: 0x8e11120> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

The modal is dismissed just fine but I don't like the warning.  I am dismissing the modal in the presenting view controller with the following:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

   [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

I have also tried with `segue.sourceViewController` with the same results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check with: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: This warning tells you that you are trying to dismiss two view controllers at the same time. Why are you sending the done method a segue?

Comment: No difference.  Any idea why the error is coming from UITabBarController and not the presenting view controller?

Comment: So I am new to storyboards... I am using a "done" button on the modal to dismiss.  I have connected the action of the "done" button to the exit of the modal and then calls the doneButtonPressed method in the presenting viewController.

Comment: From what I understand from your comment you are calling too many functions. On your modal view, you should have a "Done" button. and that button should be connected to an action that calls "dismissViewController".. No one else should try to send the modal away.

Comment: I thought it was bad style to have a modal dismiss itself.  It is better to have a delegate do that.  So, I thought this was what the "Exit" was for??

Comment: Only one person should dismiss the modal. Either itself, or the delegate. If the delegate: then the modal done button should call the delegate method responsible for dismissing it.
If the modal itself: it should call self dismissViewController.  You are mixing up both implementations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41683/discussion-between-cutetare-and-scott-sarnikowski)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... when you are unwinding don't need to explicitly dismiss the modal controller.  That comes from free from the unwind.